# Constructing multivariate polynomial from roots

Tags: polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

A polynomial that should have (real) roots at $x_1, x_2, ...$ can easily be constructed with the factored form of a (univariate) polynomial $p(x) = (x-x_1) (x-x_2) ...$.

How about the multivariate case? The multivariate polynomial should have the roots at $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ...$. How does the polynomial look like?

Comment: A multivariate polynomial typically has an infinite number of roots. For instance, $p(x,y)=y-x^2$.

Comment: They decompose into product of irreducible polynomials. The irreducible ones correspond to algebraic subvarieties of the affine space. Reference perhaps [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz)

Comment: @lhf: I see your point. What if the polynomial has to be 0 at $(x_i, y_i)$, but may also be 0 at other points?